# Decrypt or decode Facebook access token from Facebook Graph iOS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

The Facebook iOS SDK is granting encrypted or encoded access tokens in this format:

```
v9ylvkttPnuFWUX4KVdjDPB0SRXkuKX7z281rqjHuG0.eyJpdiI6ImEwWXBDaEtncWpDTU5ibUNuQWdROWcifQ.Y-DwxRY2ZAFZiP7EVuR-HksXqmGw9LXP6umGrfz2XnjSLm0a508u7_jXq0_Kz5a2S8AUUulzUvIRVxTS51_i6VfSByOCbFBIKoBe0-n-Pa8NC29wbuVmGJLvq4W-ezhv0DzA3diiCIqCybt9ELDXoA
```

Using oAuth on the web, Facebook provides unencrypted / unencoded access tokens in this format (this one is not real):

```
213455681425|1.BGgrgnfWrdpG_X18.3600.1213252135.2-1334679|dHcDbxGbeYbLg3SRgw12fdf4gd60
```

**How can I decrypt/decode the iOS access token** so that I can read the expiration unix time value and user id like I can with the unencoded tokens?  The reason I need the expiration date is to determine when it expires, and I need the user id to publish with the appID|appSecret style access token in the event the access token is expired yet the user hasn't revoked publish_stream access.

Answer (score 0):

That access token never expires since it has the offline_access permission. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/lint?access_token=IwDbeiWINrotP3JOd1EGoEY7OmOBd2DyV8lh73mutCM.eyJpdiI6IkdKd3BvWlItcWlWRzIwTGYtUkRUVWcifQ.J6qNtSibMmm0yFe2QNHG46jnIUXef3dV-NnbYqXkfrFABjPrgMPQRUeKHJ3GxX1T3nlU7-4P8FUT6dlfwSwHfNJrheTUZIXdd3AlsSRUiUer5xEdFA9IsGEMn6GyHheH9DSr76IeZcBjl-_s4ub3kg).

In this case it looks like the user expired the access token by de-authorizing the app or changing his/her password. To mitigate against this, look into using an app deauthorization callback url. Here's some more details:

> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the
>   app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a
>   Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we
>   will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter,
>   signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just
>   removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this
>   request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: That token was just an example I found online to show the format - I didn't want to paste my own in. I updated the question with an actual expired token of mine.  I am not prompting for offline_access - just publish_stream. But back to the question, is there a way to decode that token (maybe using the secret) to parse the user id / expiration timestamp?

Comment: Also looking for this information, although in my case I'm not looking specifically for the expiration, but would really like to know how to decode the token